# How do I make a perl regular expresion fail in the code block?

Tags: perl, pcre

I've got a screw I'm trying to nail in with perl and so far this is what I've got so far.

```
perl -ne '/(.+)\.(.+)\((.+)\)(.+)(?{print "match" if  ( $1 > 9 || ( $1 == 9 && $2 > 1 ) || ($1 == 9 && $2 == 1 && $3 > 7 ) || $1 == 9 && $2 == 1 && $3 == 7 && $4 > 22 ) })/' versions
```

versions:

```
9.1(7)23
9.1(7)22
8.1(7)22
7.2(33)24
55
```

it will print "match" if the version in the file is > than 9.1(7)23, which is good.

But I want the regexp to succeed, not just print "match".  How do I translate the stuff inside the code block to an actual response.  I've tried quite a few iterations with `*ACCEPT|*FAIL` but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Maybe using `(??{})` instead of `(?{})`: `/(.+)\.(.+)\((.+)\)(.+)(??{ your_condition ? "" : "(*FAIL)"})/` ? I mean, this is OK if you are writing some quick one-liner for a one time job; but if this is supposed to be maintainable, production code, then don't try to do this with just a regex of course ;)

Comment: (peharps `"(*ACCEPT)"` instead of `""`. Both work, and I have no opinion on which is "better". `ACCEPT` is more explicit I guess; but since you are writing something not readable at all, does it really matter?)

Comment: @dada yeah, it's gotta be a one liner. I'm injecting into some version matching thing into some script to help a network guy out using their own tools.  But that totally worked, thanks a lot you want to make it a legit answer to get credit?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the regex does succeed. But it does so whether the condition is true or not. I think you're actually asking for it to *fail* when the condition is false. For that, you want

```
(?(?{ condition })(*ACCEPT)|(*FAIL))
```

or just

```
(?(?{ !condition })(*FAIL))
```

Fixed:

```
perl -nle'
   print "$_: match"
      if /
         ^(.+)\.(.+)\((.+)\)(.+)\z
         (?(?{
            !( $1 > 9
            || $1 == 9 && $2 > 1
            || $1 == 9 && $2 == 1 && $3 > 7
            || $1 == 9 && $2 == 1 && $3 == 7 && $4 > 22
            )
         })(*FAIL))
      /x;
' versions
```

A far better approach is to do the check outside of the pattern.

```
perl -nle'
   print "$_: match"
      if /^(.+)\.(.+)\((.+)\)(.+)\z/
      && (
            $1 > 9
         || $1 == 9 && $2 > 1
         || $1 == 9 && $2 == 1 && $3 > 7
         || $1 == 9 && $2 == 1 && $3 == 7 && $4 > 22
      );
' versions
```

Comment: from my undrstanding `(*FAIL)` will just force to backtrack maybe `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, No idea what it does, but it's not needed